# How to make use of both Zend_Action_Controller and REST controller in Zend 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been trying to implement a Zend project which uses both `Zend_Action_Controller` and `REST controller`.But I am not able to use the default `Zend_Action_Controller`.I am able to use the REST controller.Could someone please help me how to use both the controllers in my project.Thanks in advance.

**Bootstrap.php**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
protected function _initActionHelpers()
{
    $contextSwitch = new REST_Controller_Action_Helper_ContextSwitch();
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($contextSwitch);

    $restContexts = new REST_Controller_Action_Helper_RestContexts();
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($restContexts);
}
}
```

**application.ini**

```
resources.router.routes.rest.type = Zend_Rest_Route
autoloaderNamespaces.rest = "REST_"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "REST_Controller_Plugin_RestHandler"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have been trying to implement a Zend project

If this is a new project? I strongly recommend using ZF2.

**ZF1 is not supported anymore**. *Even ZF3 is being planned at the moment.*

ZF2 has so many benefits over ZF1, you will be able to do the above very easily in v2.*.